# How to copy and paste outside an Electron app?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-packager

Sorry in advance if my question was already answered, as for me i didn't found any answer when I searched. I'm currently building an Angular Desktop app, using Electron and so electron-packager. I need to be able to copy and paste text from inside the app to another window, and same in he other way. I can already copy and paste if I stay inside the app. 
I already tried many solutions suggested by the community, as you'll see in my code, by adding a Menu to my app, with the copy and paste shortcuts.

Here is my code below launching the electron window (main.js) :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({icon:  path.join(__dirname, `/src/logo4.ico`)});
  win.maximize();

  // Create the Application's main menu
  const template = [{
    label: "Application",
    submenu: [
      {label: "About Application", selector: "orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:"},
      {type: "separator"},
      {
        label: "Quit", accelerator: "Command+Q", click: function () {
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {
    label: "Edit",
    submenu: [
      {label: "Undo", accelerator: "Ctrl+Z", selector: "undo:"},
      {label: "Redo", accelerator: "Shift+Ctrl+Z", selector: "redo:"},
      {type: "separator"},
      {label: "Cut", accelerator: "Ctrl+X", selector: "cut:"},
      {label: "Copy", accelerator: "Ctrl+C", selector: "copy:"},
      {label: "Paste", accelerator: "Ctrl+V", selector: "paste:"},
      {label: "Select All", accelerator: "Ctrl+A", selector: "selectAll:"}
    ]
  }
  ];

  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
  // Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

  // load the dist folder from Angular
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );

  // The following is optional and will open the DevTools:
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

// on macOS, closing the window doesn't quit the app
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// initialize the app's main window
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

As you can see i tried to add the menu and the shortcuts to the app. It works fine to copy and paste within the app but not more, even though the sources I found indicates that it's supposed to work outside too. Hope you'll be able to help me :) 
I'm already sure the problem has nothing to do with angular or the packager, as I tried to copy and paste from the window opened by `electron .`, on a simple html form, and it was still not working. Here is the form below, just in case you need it :

```
<div class="login-wrapper" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">

  <mat-card class="box">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Log in</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" [ngClass]="{'error': loginForm.controls['username'].errors && !loginForm.controls['username'].pristine}" dividerColor="{{loginForm.controls['username'].errors && !loginForm.controls['username'].pristine ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}">
          <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['username'].errors && !loginForm.hasError('required')" class="error-msg">
             Username is required !
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].errors && !loginForm.hasError('required')" class="error-msg">
            Password is required
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card-content>
      <button type="submit"  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" class="btn-block" color="accent" mat-stroked-button><span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
        Log in</button>
    </form>
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="remember" (change)="rememberChange()"> Remember 
         me</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-card>

    </div>
```

Have a great day and thanks in advance to the community

I'm using Angular 8.2.13, electron 7.1.1 and electron-packager 13.1.1. I package my app for Windows.

N.B : i'm new to posting on StackOverflow, sorry if my post is not on the right place

Comment: The electron version and platform you are running on may be relevant here. From your code - I guess you run on MacOS? What kind of content do you try to copy?

Comment: I changed this thanks. No i'm running on Windows and i try just to copy text, to copy and paste serial numbers and products codes into the app

Comment: Ah now I see - you try to copy text from outside into the app - not from the app to the outside as I assumed - thanks for clarifying this :) So, you have a text field or form you want to copy stuff into, right?

Comment: Yep, got a form with several inputs, where i would like to be able to paste text from outside the app. And it would be nice to be able to copy from the app and paste it outside the app too. But i guess once one is done the other is quite the same process.

Comment: You can do one thing in the meantime - eliminate angular by loading a simple html with a form in your window and see whether your problem persists. If yes, try with a different electron version to exclude the possibility of an electron bug.

Comment: Well i think it's coming from electron because when i run my app in the browser with ng serve, copy and past works fine, but the problem start when i package it with electron.

Comment: You still want to do that, because it is easier to debug if you have a simple html instead of a complex angular app and you have a prepared sample project in case you need to file a bug report. If you start your project with the electron runtime instead of building it and then starting it - do you still have the problem (excluding problems in the packaged format)?

Comment: When you talk about start the project with the electron runtime, are you talking about ng build --base-href ./ && electron . ? I'm sorry if I got some difficulties to get some stuff, it's my first angular and electron project haha

Comment: :) no problem, and yes, `electron .` to take the packager out of the picture for now

Comment: Well i just checked, and with `electron .` i'm still not able to copy and paste, and i check with a simple html form (my login form)

Comment: Very good, you now have definite proof that your problem has nothing to do with angular and the packager - if you edit your question to include your html and update your already contained main script, that'll increase your chances of getting an answer. Sadly I can't reproduce your problem - I can copy and paste in both directions via keyboard ctrl+c ctrl+v. Maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help, i changed as u said, hoping that someone will be able to help me :) have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who could have the same issue as me, I fixed it. In fact it had nothing to do with the code, just the company antivirus which was putting my app in quarantine everytime I was starting it. Whitelisted it,n and everything worked for copy and paste. Just sad I didn't figured it out earlier